# Passing new shape to `np.reshape`

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Within [`numpy.ndarray.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html), the `shape` parameter is an *int or tuple of ints*, and

> The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an
>   integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length.

The documentation signature is just:

```
# Note this question doesn't apply to the function version, `np.reshape`
np.ndarray.reshape(shape, order='C')
```

In practice the specification doesn't seem to be this strict.  From the description above I would expect to need to use:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(12)
b = a.reshape((4,3))  # (4,3) is passed to `newshape`
```

But instead I can get away with just:

```
c = a.reshape(4,3)  # Seems like just 4 would be passed to `newshape`
                    #     and 3 would be passed to next parameter, `order`
print(np.array_equal(b,c))
# True
```

How is it that I can do this?  I know that if I just simply enter `2, 3` into a Python shell, it is technically a tuple whether I use parentheses or not.  But the comparison above seems to violate basic laws of how positional parameters are passed to the dict of keyword args.  I.e.:

```
def f(a, b=1, order='c'):
    print(a)
    print(b)

f((4,3))
print()
f(4,3)

# (4, 3)
# 1
#
# 4
# 3
```

...and there are no star operators in `reshape`.  (Something akin to `def f(*a, order='c')` above.)

Comment: It can do this with `def foo(*a, order='c')`

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon Yes, and if `reshape` used something like `*shape`, both of the above alternatives "working" would make more sense.  But there are no star operators in `reshape`--hence my question.

Comment: The actual signature doesn't match the documentation. There's nothing magic going on, just undocumented behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 Would you say `np.ndarray.reshape(*shape, order='c')` would be more appropriate then?

Comment: @BradSolomon: Yes, with a note that the shape can either be passed as separate positional args or as a tuple.

Comment: @BradSolomon: [There's already an open issue.](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/570)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the way that parameters are bound with normal Python methods, it should not work, but the method is not a Python method at all. Numpy is an extension module for CPython, and `numpy.ndarray.reshape` is actually [implemented in C](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L173-L211).

If you look at the implementation, the `order` parameter is only ever read as a keyword argument. A positional argument will never be bound to it, unlike with a normal Python method where the second positional argument would be bound to `order`.  The C code tries to build the value for `newshape` from all of the positional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing magic going on. The function's signature just doesn't match the documentation. It's documented as

```
ndarray.reshape(shape, order='C')
```

but it's written in C, and instead of doing the C-api equivalent of

```
def reshape(self, shape, order='C'):
```

it does the C-api equivalent of manual `*args` and `**kwargs` handling. You can take a look in [`numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.3/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L171). (Note that the C-api equivalent of `def reshape(self, shape, order='C'):` would have the same C-level signature as what the current code is doing, but it would immediately use something like [`PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html) to parse the arguments instead of doing manual handling.)