# What is the difference between single and double bracket Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a=np.random.randn(1, 2)
b=np.zeros((1,2))
print("Data type of A: ",type(a))
print("Data type of A: ",type(b))
```

Output:

```
Data type of A:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Data type of A:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

In np.zeros(), to declare an array we give the input in 2 brackets whereas in np.random.radn(), we give it in 1 bracket?

Is there any specific reason for the syntax,as both of them are of same data type but follow a different syntax?

Comment: This is similar to a recent question about why the `np.reshape` requires the shape tuple, while `x.reshape(...)` accepts the expanded tuple `(2,3)` and `((2,3))`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508340/passing-new-shape-to-np-reshape

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an effort to ease the transition for Matlab users to NumPy, some convenience functions like `randn` were built which use the same call signature as their Matlab equivalents.

The more NumPy-centric (as opposed to Matlab-centric) NumPy functions (such as `np.zeros`) expect the `size` (or `shape`) to be a tuple.  This allows other parameters like `dtype` and `order` to be passed to the function as well.
The Matlab-centric functions assume all the arguments are part of the size.

[`np.random.randn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) is one of NumPy's Matlab-centric convenience functions, modeled after [Matlab's randn](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop). The more NumPy-centric alternative to `np.random.randn` is [`np.random.standard_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.standard_normal.html#numpy.random.standard_normal).